# Python: script that takes a text file and produces another text file with certain lines modified

Tags: python, parsing

I'm writing a python script that takes a text file and should produce another text file with certain lines minimally changed.

I keep getting stuck and would appreciate some assistance.

The intention is that from the commandline I can run:

```
$ ./script_j_to_uj.py eval_c_sensor.j eval_c_sensor.uj
```

and that the .uj contains the .j text with the specified changes.
My code so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys

input = open(sys.argv[1])
output = open(sys.argv[2], 'w')
for s in input.xreadlines(  ):
   output.write(s.replace("lib_c_support", "lljvm/lib/lib_c_support"))
   output.write(s.replace(".method public <clinit>()V", ".method static <clinit>()V"))
   output.write(s.replace("invokestatic java/lang/lljvm/lib/c/exit(I)V", ";;;; invokestatic java/lang/lljvm/lib/c/exit(I)V"))
   output.write(s.replace(".method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V", ".method public static main()V"))
   output.write(s.replace("invokestatic eval_c_sensor/main()I", "invokestatic eval_c_sensor/main2()I"))
   output.write(s.replace(".method public static main()I", ".method public static main2()I"))
output.close(  )
input.close(  )
```

But this produces errors. I believe my first mistake is in viewing the text file, but I'm not certain.
The error is:

```
  File "C:/Users/SvenA/OneDrive/Documents/temp/script.py", line 6, in <module>
    for s in input.xreadlines(  ):
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'xreadlines'
```

Comment: show your errors plz

Comment: "But this produces errors." - *Which* ones?

Comment: You understand that you're writing 6 lines of output per line of input, right?

Comment: Ah, now that I think about that, that makes sense. Thanks! one of the errors beyond the first one I imagine.

Comment: input.xreadlines or input.readlines?  Python3 or Python2 Interpreter?

Comment: I'm confusing with another method I realize, but changing it to readlines works, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you intended to write something similar to:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import os, sys

    with open(sys.argv[1]) as input:
        # Ensure the output file is empty
        with open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as output:
            output.write('')

        # Write all of the lines
        with open(sys.argv[2], 'a') as output:
            for s in input.readlines():
                output.write(s.replace("lib_c_support", "lljvm/lib/lib_c_support"
                     ).replace(".method public <clinit>()V", ".method static <clinit>()V"
                     ).replace("invokestatic java/lang/lljvm/lib/c/exit(I)V", ";;;; invokestatic java/lang/lljvm/lib/c/exit(I)V"
                     ).replace(".method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V", ".method public static main()V"
                     ).replace("invokestatic eval_c_sensor/main()I", "invokestatic eval_c_sensor/main2()I"
                     ).replace(".method public static main()I", ".method public static main2()I"))
```

My code is still a bit of a mess, but you seemed to have three problems:

1. Writing 6 times instead of 1
2. Using 'w'rite instead of 'a'ppend as mode, and
3. Using `xreadlines` instead of `readlines`.